# C++ Swap Template

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
void swap (T &a, T &b) {
  T aux (a);

  a = b;
  b = aux;
}

int main() {

  string a = "Hello", b = "Good Bye";
  cout << "[" << a << ", " << b << "]" << endl;

  swap(a, b);
  cout << "[" << a << ", " << b << "]" << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

El código anterior funciona correctamente, sin embargo si añado más código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
void swap (T &a, T &b) {
  T aux (a);

  a = b;
  b = aux;
}

int main() {

  string a = "Hello", b = "Good Bye";
  cout << "[" << a << ", " << b << "]" << endl;

  swap(a, b);
  cout << "[" << a << ", " << b << "]" << endl;

  float f1(3.0), f2(2.5);
  cout << "[" << f1 << ", " << f2 << "]" << endl;

  swap(f1, f2);
  cout << "[" << f1 << ", " << f2 << "]" << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Obtengo un error de compilación
error: call of overloaded 'wap(float&, float&)' is ambiguous
candidate void swap(T&, T&) [with T = float]

Estoy empleando en la compilación -std=c++11 y -lstdc++ en g++ con Debian.

No entiendo porqué no funciona con float, int etc.

Comment: Conflcito de espacios de nombres ([std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/)), quita el "bendito" `using namespace std;` y mira que pasa... También puedes cambiar el nombre "swap" en tu plantilla por otra cosa, pero como dice el zen de Python, aunque estemos en C++ no es mala idea general : "Explícito mejor que implícito", eso va por el using namespace...

Comment: Muchas gracias, y me apunto lo mejor explícito que implícito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap es una función predefinida. Bien podrías quitar el `namespace` como te indican, o podrías renombrar tu método para que no genere conflictos:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
void myswap (T &a, T &b) {
  T aux (a);

  a = b;
  b = aux;
}

int main() {

  string a = "Hello", b = "Good Bye";
  cout << "[" << a << ", " << b << "]" << endl;

  myswap(a, b);
  cout << "[" << a << ", " << b << "]" << endl;

  float f1(3.0);
  float f2(2.5);
  cout << "[" << f1 << ", " << f2 << "]" << endl;

  myswap(f1, f2);
  cout << "[" << f1 << ", " << f2 << "]" << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Es lo sugerido en las respuestas a esta pregunta en SO original https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789414/call-of-overloaded-swapfloat-float-is-ambiguous

Comment: Muchas gracias. Entendido. Lo había buscado antes de preguntar pero no con la suficiente pericia. Si hubiera añadido "ambiguous" habría salido a la primera. De nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Con `std::string` no falla porque `std::swap` ya tiene una sobrecarga para `std::string`. Básicamente, si no existiese tu `using namespace std`, tendrías las tres siguientes sobrecargas (dichas sobrecargas no son exáctamente así, pero para simplificar):

```
template<class T>
void std::swap(T& a, T& b);

void std::swap(std::string& a, std::string& b);

template<class T
void ::swap(T& a, T& b);
```

Y al traer el espacio de nombres `std` al espacio de nombres global con `using namespace std`:

```
template<class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b); // std

void swap(std::string& a, std::string& b); // std

template<class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b); // Tuya propia: conflicto con std::swap
```

Qué pasa, qué en tu primer ejemplo, al intercambiar los dos `std::string`, el compilador vé que la segunda sobrecarga es un "better match" de tu intento de llamada, es decir, que es más especializada, así que se elige esa, y las otras dos no generan conflicto de ambigüedad.

Sin embargo, cuando intentas swapear dos objetos de cualquier otro tipo que no tengan sobrecargas especializadas (`int`, `float`, etc), entonces se intenta elegir cualquiera de las otras dos funciones y, al no poder elegir entre las dos dado que ninguna es más especializada que la otra, genera conflicto de ambigüedad.

¿Por qué la simple presencia de tu propia sobrecarga no genera dicho conflicto en el primer ejemplo? Porque son plantillas: las plantillas tienen la característica de no instanciarse a no ser que se usen. Cuando solo intentas swapear dos strings, ambas sobrecargas (`std::swap` y `::swap`), al no ser usadas, no se intentan instanciar ni generan código (no tendrán presencia alguna en ensamblador, pa' entendernos).